# gpg command inside docker container

Tags: .net, docker, gnupg

I'm building a .NET application which uses gpg command, but I don't know how to add gpg to the docker image. Currently when I try to execute gpg command inside the container I get:
bash: gpg: command not found

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env

RUN apt-get install tar
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gpg

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Comment: Only the content after the final `FROM` line is included in the final image.  You're installing `gpg` in the build stage but not in the final image.

Comment: Are you trying to sign something prior to the final image creation? You only made it available in the initial container